# Do convolution encoders exist with two separate (independent) inputs?

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding

Do convolution encoders exist with two separate (independent) inputs?

I got the question in my mind when I saw the question attached here.   [image]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

> Do convolution encoders exist with two separate (independent) inputs?

Yes, such *convolutional* encoders do exist, and the diagram that is included in your question is an example of such an encoder. The code that is generated is called a (3,2) convolutional code.

Now what is your *real* question?

Comment: My question is the question in the attached image itself.  I know how to find the codeword if one input is given.   But what we should do if two or more inputs are given, I do not know.  Can you throw some light on this?

Comment: One can calculate the codeword given the two inputs/messages but in such a case, the codeword will depend on both the inputs/messages as against codeword depending on a singe input/message normally.  Where is it used?

Comment: @SeethaRamaRajuSanapala Think of the convolutional encoder as a state machine. Are state machines limited to having only one input?

Comment: No.  It is just that I have not come across before - I have not come across filters with 2 inputs.  But you can find always the output if the filer is given 2 inputs from two different points.